# Как визуализировать данные от API Яндекс.Метрики в jQuery.flot.chart.js?

Tags: php, jquery, flot, яндекс-директ

Нужно сделать дашборд для админки, нашел интересную библиотеку (flot.js), но на вход она хочет принимать массив такого вида `[[0,1],[1,3],[2,-4],[3,2],[4,0.5],[5,0.7],[6,-1],[7,4],[8,2]]`, где первая это ось у, а вторая х. Но, API Яндекс.Метрики дает JSON такого вида:

```
array(5) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#5 (11) {
   ["wday"]=>
   int(0)
   ["denial"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visits"]=>
   int(2)
   ["new_visitors_perc"]=>
   int(0)
   ["page_views"]=>
   int(13)
   ["date"]=>
   string(8) "20141006"
   ["visit_time"]=>
   int(1243)
   ["depth"]=>
   float(6.5)
   ["new_visitors"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visitors"]=>
   int(1)
   ["id"]=>
   string(8) "20141006"
 }
 [1]=>
 object(stdClass)#6 (11) {
   ["wday"]=>
   int(6)
   ["denial"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visits"]=>
   int(2)
   ["new_visitors_perc"]=>
   int(0)
   ["page_views"]=>
   int(2)
   ["date"]=>
   string(8) "20141005"
   ["visit_time"]=>
   int(15)
   ["depth"]=>
   int(1)
   ["new_visitors"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visitors"]=>
   int(2)
   ["id"]=>
   string(8) "20141005"
 }
 [2]=>
 object(stdClass)#7 (11) {
   ["wday"]=>
   int(5)
   ["denial"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visits"]=>
   int(1)
   ["new_visitors_perc"]=>
   int(0)
   ["page_views"]=>
   int(1)
   ["date"]=>
   string(8) "20141004"
   ["visit_time"]=>
   int(16)
   ["depth"]=>
   int(1)
   ["new_visitors"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visitors"]=>
   int(1)
   ["id"]=>
   string(8) "20141004"
 }
 [3]=>
 object(stdClass)#8 (11) {
   ["wday"]=>
   int(4)
   ["denial"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visits"]=>
   int(1)
   ["new_visitors_perc"]=>
   int(0)
   ["page_views"]=>
   int(1)
   ["date"]=>
   string(8) "20141003"
   ["visit_time"]=>
   int(15)
   ["depth"]=>
   int(1)
   ["new_visitors"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visitors"]=>
   int(1)
   ["id"]=>
   string(8) "20141003"
 }
 [4]=>
 object(stdClass)#9 (11) {
   ["wday"]=>
   int(3)
   ["denial"]=>
   int(0)
   ["visits"]=>
   int(2)
   ["new_visitors_perc"]=>
   int(1)
   ["page_views"]=>
   int(62)
   ["date"]=>
   string(8) "20141002"
   ["visit_time"]=>
   int(5391)
   ["depth"]=>
   int(31)
   ["new_visitors"]=>
   int(2)
   ["visitors"]=>
   int(2)
   ["id"]=>
   string(8) "20141002"
 }
}
```

Мне для отображения посетителей нужны значения `visits` и `date`. Но как их вытащить и засунуть в массив который нужен flot`у?

ЗЫ: прошу прощения за столь сумбурное описание задачи, мысли путаются так как сутки уж не спал!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил так:
для начала не `json_decode($text)` а `json_decode($text, true);`
получаем массив из ассоциативных массивов, далее `array_filter` по ключам которые нам нужны, получаем массив пар.

Далее просто отдаем для нашего js уже свой массив.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать **формат `CSV`**-файла при обращении. В ряде случаев это более удобное решение. Просто поменяйте в строке запроса `.json` на `.csv`

`btw`, было бы неплохо увидеть саму строку запроса (без токена, естественно)